# Struts 2 display tags

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I have a JSP which has below tags the data in `resultsList` fed in some action and forwarded to below jsp here I would like to get the data back into the other action based on the checkbox selection. Please help, can do using Struts1 but don't like to turn back to Struts1 since started using Struts2.

```xml
<display:table class="displaytag" id="row" style="font-size:1.4em;" name="resultsList" requestURI="/SomePath.action">
  <display:column property="businessType" title="Business Type"></display:column>
  <display:column property="structure" title="Structure"></display:column>
  <display:column property="tradeSubType" title="Trade Sub Type"></display:column>
  <display:column property="businessGroup" title="Business Group"></display:column>
  <display:column title="Select To Copy" align="center">
    <s:checkbox name="selectToCopy" fieldValue="false" value="false" label="Check Me To Download"></s:checkbox>
  </display:column>
</display:table>
```

The data will be fetched in one action and forwarded to the jsp where jsp contains above display tag and now I need to submit the form and action should receive the checked information to process further. Any help here is really appreciated, I can do it using Struts1 no doubt but would like to continue in Struts2.

Comment: Not clear. You don't have a form anywhere.

Comment: I have form, when I submit I am getting only checkbox value as true or false in the model object instead I am expecting all other properties values as well in the model object.

Comment: Use hidden fields.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr M,Absolutely I have tried using hidden fields but I couldn't get the values, so I just did as below and I couldn't post the answer do not know about this site acceptance on posting answer, however its small snippet what I have done is shown below.<display:table class="displaytag" id="row" style="font-size:1.4em;" name="resultsList" requestURI="/SomePath.action"> <display:column title="Business Type"></display:column><s:property name="resultsList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].sourceSystem" id="sourceSystem%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}" value="%{#attr.row.sourceSystem}"/></display:column>WORKS

Comment: Hi beendr,Absolutely I have tried using hidden fields but I couldn't get the values, so I just did as below and I couldn't post the answer do not know about this site acceptance on posting answer, however its small snippet what I have done is shown below.<display:column title="Product Group"><s:property value="%{#attr.row.productGroup}"/>  <s:textfield name="resultsList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].productGroup" id="productGroup%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}" value="%{#attr.row.productGroup}" hidden="true"></s:textfield></display:column> Couldn't get values by using only hidden so got values as above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your action class sends some domain objects from this type:

```java
public class MyData {
    private Integer id;
    private String businessType;
    //other params
    //getter/setters
}
```

And your action class, that ist invoked before accessing the displaytag jsp page has a list of objects form type `MyData`:

```java
public class MyDisplayTagAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List<MyData> myDataList;
    //other params
    //getter/setter
    public String execute() {
        myDataList = getMyDataListFromSomewhere();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The JSP should contain a form and a submit button. Moreover you have to define every data you want to send back as a field in that form. If the user is not allowed to change them, use hidden fields. The `#attr.row.id` access printing that id to the value. `#attr` is from ognl to access the variable `row` defined from displaytag. (For more info: [Struts OGNL](http://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl-basics.html))

```xml
<s:form action="myStrutsPostAction" method="post">
    <display:table name="myDataList" uid="row">
        <display:column>
            <s:checkbox name="resultsList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].selectToCopy" id="check%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}" value="%{#attr.row.selectToCopy}"/>
        </display:column>
        <display:column>
            <input type="hidden" name="resultsList[<s:property value='%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}'/>]" value="<s:property value='%{#attr.row.businessType}' />"/>
            <s:property value="%{#attr.row.businessType}"/>
        </display:column 
    </display:table>
    <s:submit>
</s:form>
```

The post action class (the one that takes the form request) should contain a list, that was defined in the `<s:form>` and struts will set only the the data into this list.

```java
public class MyPostAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List<MyData> resultsList = new ArrayList<>();
    //getter/setter
}
```

Comment: Thanks Beendr for your reply. Here I have to send all columns data to the action. However I am getting the check box value as true or false but I couldn't get the other fields values to the action. My screen has 10 records which has been displayed using pagination, when I submit the form with 1 or 2 check boxes I am getting all 10 records respective model objects in action but only with check box value as true or false but not getting values of all other properties of the model.

Comment: Thanks Beendr for your reply. Here I have to send all columns data to the action.I am getting the check box value as true or false but I couldn't get the other properties values to the action. My screen has 10 records which is displayed using pagination, when I submit the form with 1 or 2 checked I am getting all 10 records respective model objects in action but only check box value as true or false but not getting values of all other properties of the model.One more point here to mention is I do not have ids to carry to action based on selection, instead record data is required.Thanks.

Comment: In addition to the above code, I made changes to get the checkbox value as true or false to get the value from model in action class.    <s:checkbox name="resultsList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].selectToCopy" id="check%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}" value="%{#attr.row.selectToCopy}"></s:checkbox>   In the same way I am trying to get the other properties values but I couldn't.

Comment: Hey @bharath, I changed my answer. Maybe you could try hidden fields. But sending all the data back to the server is somehow unusual, you should consider only transfer the data the user really is able to change.

Comment: Hi beendr,Absolutely I have tried using hidden fields but I couldn't get the values, so I just did as below and I couldn't post the answer do not know about this site acceptance on posting answer, however its small snippet what I have done is shown below.<display:table class="displaytag" id="row" style="font-size:1.4em;" name="resultsList" requestURI="/SomePath.action">
  <display:column title="Business Type"></display:column><s:property name="resultsList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].sourceSystem" id="sourceSystem%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}" value="%{#attr.row.sourceSystem}"/></display:column>

Comment: Hi beendr,Absolutely I have tried using hidden fields but I couldn't get the values, so I just did as below and I couldn't post the answer do not know about this site acceptance on posting answer, however its small snippet what I have done is shown below.<display:column title="Product Group"><s:property value="%{#attr.row.productGroup}"/>  <s:textfield name="resultsList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].productGroup" id="productGroup%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}" value="%{#attr.row.productGroup}" hidden="true"></s:textfield></display:column> Couldn't get values by using only hidden so got values as above.